# Identify user in a Bash script called by sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

If I create the script `/root/bin/whoami.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
```

and this script is called by a user with a properly configured sudo, it will indicate

```
root
```

Is there a fast way to obtain the actual user in a script, or will I have to resort to parameters passing along this username?

Answer (score 169):

$SUDO_USER doesn't work if you are using `sudo su -`.
It also requires multiple checks - if `$USER == 'root'` then get `$SUDO_USER`.

Instead of the command `whoami` use `who am i`.  This runs the `who` command filtered for the current session.  It gives you more info than you need.  So, do this to get just the user:

```
who am i | awk '{print $1}'
```

Alternatively (and simpler) you can use `logname`.  It does the same thing as the above statement.

This gives you the username that logged in to the session.

These work regardless of `sudo` or `sudo su [whatever]`.  It also works regardless of how many times `su` and `sudo` are called.

Comment: Alternative to `who am i` is `who mom likes`. Your choice.

Comment: `who` returns 2 lines for me, both containing my name, and `who am i` returns none. Any help?

Comment: I notice that this doesn't work in a docker container, as the `who am i` seems to depend on login and thus returns blank. Try `docker run -it ubuntu bash`, and `whoami` gives the user (root in this case, but works correctly with alternate users), while `who am i` is blank.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `owner() { ls -ld $1 | awk '{print $3}'; }` in my script to get the owner string; usage: `if [ "$(owner $file)" != $(logname) ]`

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and the command `who am i` does nothing, it seems to be simply `who`, so `who | awk '{print $1}'` works as expected ;)

Comment: Just incase you don't have `awk` installed, you can also use `cut`:

`who mom likes | cut -d' ' -f1`

or `sed` for some reason:

`who mom likes | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: I have question. If I have the following script :
  `1 #~/bin/bash
  2 
  3 USERNAME=`who am i`
  4 
  5 echo "$USERNAME" `
~                   
and if I execute `sed -n 5p ./second.sh | sudo bash`  and on the terminal "root" is printed instead of the user with whom I execute this command?

Comment: Note: `logname` doesn't work when you run it from a terminal window because it's a non-login terminal.

Comment: Interestingly `who` returns my graphical and numerous (tmux) sessions, while `who am i` returns only the current session where I am running the command. This could get interesting where you might need a `head -1` or to try `who am i` if you see more than $# = 1 lines in the first return. If I run a script as another user that has sudo permissions to a specific path that is NOT my primary login user (say a service account that needs to run eg nginx with sudo to grab port 80) I'm not sure what it will return.

Comment: @daveoncode: your approach works if your current user was the first to log in... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429361/1587329 seems to work in all cases

Answer (score 67):

I think [$SUDO_USER](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html#SUDO_USER) is valid.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $SUDO_USER
whoami
```

Comment: Strange thing: `sudo env` shows `SUDO_USER` but `sudo echo $SUDO_USER` prints nothing...

Comment: job, this is not strange, it's expected.  in `sudo echo $SUDO_USER`, bash is evaluating $SUDO_USER **before** executing sudo.  try the script posted in this solution, it works.

Comment: @quadmore: If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: You could also use `echo ${SUDO_USER:-$USER}` to catch both `sudo` and non-sudo running. But [evan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597929/321973) `logname` sounds easer

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - And as evan points out, `$SUDO_USER` doesn't work with `sudo su -`, but `logname` always works.

Comment: sudo sh -c "echo \$SUDO_USER"

Answer (score 15):

Here is how to get the username of the person who called the script no matter if sudo or not:

```
if [ $SUDO_USER ]; then user=$SUDO_USER; else user=`whoami`; fi
```

or a shorter version

```
[ $SUDO_USER ] && user=$SUDO_USER || user=`whoami`
```

Comment: even shorter: `user=${SUDO_USER:-$(whoami)}` or [`user=$(logname)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597929/321973)

Answer (score 8):

Using `whoami`, `who am i`, `who`, `id` or `$SUDO_USER` isn't right here.

Actually, `who` is never a solution to the question, as it will only list the logged in users, which might be dozens...

In my eyes, the only valuable answer is the use of `logname`.

Hope this helps

Rob

Answer (score 5):

If it's the UID you're looking for (useful for docker shenanigans), then this works:

```
LOCAL_USER_ID=$(id -u $(logname))
```

Answer (score 2):

`who am i | awk '{print $1}'` didn't work for me but
`who|awk '{print $1}'` will serve the job

Comment: Not on a host where more than one user has session

Comment: It's `whoami` all one word, not `who am i`. This follows typical structure where shell commands typically are a single word, with arguments following. `who am i` would be interpereted as running the command `who` with the arguments of `am` and `i`. `who` just so happens to also be a command, but it outputs more than is needed in this case, whereas `whoami` just prints the username.

Comment: @EliSmith `whoami` doesn't solve the problem, because it doesn't look for the caller via root.

Answer (score 1):

Odd, the system does distinguish between [real and effective UIDs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getuid.html), but I can find no program that exports this at shell level.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same question, using Rocky Linux 9.2, I ran this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "LOGNAME: $LOGNAME"
echo "SUDO_USER: $SUDO_USER"
set | grep username
```

in each of these scenarios:

- as user (`./script.sh`)

  - LOGNAME: username
  - SUDO_USER: null
- as root via sudo (`sudo ./script.sh`)

  - LOGNAME: root
  - SUDO_USER: username
- as root via su  (`./script.sh`)

  - LOGNAME: username
  - SUDO_USER: null
- as root via sudo su  (`./script.sh`)

  - LOGNAME: root
  - SUDO_USER: username

Using an if...then...else check would work, unless you inadvertently `sudo` run the script while you are already at the `superuser` prompt:

```
#root: sudo ./script.sh
```

- via either su or sudo su the results are

  - LOGNAME: root
  - SUDO_USER: root

However, one `set` variable has proven to be consistent though all of my scenarios:

```
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/username
```

I now set the logged in user as:

```
UNAME=$(echo $MAIL |cut -d/ -f5)
```

I'm sure there are situations where this would not work, but I haven't found one yet.