# Who I was before I sudo to root

Tags: bash, root, sudo

I'm working in a script, the script runs as root. But I need to log who I was before I sudo to root.
Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: `who am i` tells you who you are, even after a `sudo`.  At least for the simple cases...there may be chains of operations which lead that to break down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [identify user in a bash script called by sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522341/identify-user-in-a-bash-script-called-by-sudo)

Answer (score 3):

The sudo manual shows that $SUDO_USER should give you the original user's username and $SUDO_UID gives the original user's UID.