# How to access $USER in inner sudo-bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a simple script like this to write into a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo bash -c 'cat <<EOT >> foo/bar.txt
  Hello ${USER}
EOT'
```

When I run it the content of `foo/bar.txt` is:

```
Hello root
```

My username:

```
$ whoami
timo
```

So I expected it to output "Hello timo". The result of "Hello root" does make sense though since I run it through the sudo command.

Is there any way to access the user name of the "outer bash" somehow, so it outputs "Hello timo" instead of "Hello root"?

---

**Update** 2018-12-04

I'd like to point out that I saw that [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522341/identify-user-in-a-bash-script-called-by-sudo) before opening this question and the suggestions from there didn't work (`who am i` and `logname`). The only option that actually worked is the accepted answer from this thread by kvantour using `${SUDO_USER}`. In the other post it was suggested that this wouldn't work:

> `$SUDO_USER doesn't work if you are using sudo su -`

So, no need to downvote imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo bash -c 'cat - <<EOF >> foo/bar.txt
  Hello ${SUDO_USER}
EOF'
```

> `sudo` utilizes the following environment variables:
>
> - **`SUDO_GID`:**  Set to the group ID of the user who invoked sudo.
> - **`SUDO_USER`:** Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.
>
> **<sub>source: `man sudo`</sub>**

If you cannot use `SUDO_USER` and it has to be `USER`, then you have to double quote your string your parse to bash. Double quotes will still substitute the variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo bash -c "cat - <<EOF >> foo/bar.txt
  Hello ${USER}
EOF"
```

Comment: Timo is mentioning that he is running command under sudo, so he needs to access user who called sudo, if understood well.

Comment: Works! Perfect answer, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

This should work for You. Replace `${USER}` with this:

```
$(who -m | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

`who -m` provides further login info that's why cut first field

Comment: This code snippet does not produce any output on my machine. This doesn't seem really portable.

Comment: What platform are You on. who command is under GNU core utilities: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/who-invocation.html#who-invocation

Comment: OSX. It uses BSD utils. OP didn't indicate which distro they are running their script from, so assuming they are using a system compatible with GNU coreutils is a bit far fetched