# Testing home directory of current user with sudo

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a small CLI script that checks for the existence of a file in a user's home directory:

```
$ do_my_script
```

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -e ~/.myfiledirectory/.myfile; then ... do something
```

It works great when I run it as my logged in user. Though, this script needs to be run as `sudo` sometimes...

```
sudo do_my_script
```

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -e ~/.myfiledirecotry/.myfile; then ... do something
```

If I run it as sudo... I belive it is checking the super user's home directory for the existence of the file, instead of the logged in user's home directory.

I am trying to get it to always check the currently logged in user's home directory for the existence of the file, regardless if the command is run as `sudo` or not.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522341/identify-user-in-a-bash-script-called-by-sudo ?

Comment: Although it might be easier to call `sudo` only inside the script when needed.

Comment: Other users might not have permissions to other users home directories